# Missing currencies in symfony 1.4 with sweden culture

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony1, currency

I have to build a multi-language application with currency exchange function using Diem 5.1 (actually it's symfony 1.4). I rely on sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCurrency, but it throws exception with sweden culture:

> The following currencies do not exist:
>   BGN, MXN, RUB

The widget initialization is:

```
sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCurrency->configure(array(
'culture' => 'sw',
'currencies' => array('HUF', 'AUD', 'BGN', 'BRL', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'CNY', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'HRK', 'ISK', 'JPY', 'KRW', 'LTL', 'LVL', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'RON', 'RSD', 'RUB', 'SEK', 'SGD', 'TRY', 'UAH', 'USD', 'ZAR'), 'add_empty' => false, 'default' => 'EUR'
))
```

The currencies come from a webservice so I can't simply remove the failing ones.
With other cultures everything works fine.

Is there somewhere a solution/patch/something? Or how can I add the missing currencies myself?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the missing currencies like this:

```
$cur = array_diff(
  array('HUF', 'AUD', 'BGN', 'BRL', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'CNY', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'HKD', 'HRK', 'ISK', 'JPY', 'KRW', 'LTL', 'LVL', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'RON', 'RSD', 'RUB', 'SEK', 'SGD', 'TRY', 'UAH', 'USD', 'ZAR'),
  array('BGN', 'MXN', 'RUB')
);  


$w = new sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCurrency(array(
'culture' => 'sw',
'currencies' => $cur,
'add_empty' => false, 
'default' => 'EUR',
));

echo $w->render('cur');
```

The Exception comes from sfCultureInfo.php (line 761) where the requested currencies are compared to the predefined ones, so that symfony can enshure to handle them.

What could but **SHOULD NOT BE DONE** is to alter the root.dat and add the missing currencies, but i guess that is not all, and it will alter your symfony core code (bad)

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to use them properly, and remove them like this only if there's no way to add the missing data...

Comment: Since these are valid currencies (BGN=Bulgarian lev, MXN=Mexican peso, RUB=Russian rubel) the root.dat already contains them, and with other cultures everything works fine. I did modify the sw.dat, and the problem is gone.
Thanks for pointing me to this direction!

Comment: OK. I didn't check if they are in the root.dat. You could check if this is already a bug at the symfony website, and submit your correction.